Importing modules From Different Packages And Run it as a Script
Test
    |
     TestP1
           |
            __init__.py
            hello.py
    |
     TestP2
           |
            __init__.py
            greet.py
    |
     app.py


I have this folder structure. And I use a function inside hello module from TestP1 package in the greet module in the TestP2 package. And what I'm confusing right now is when run that greet.py as a script it shows me module not found error. But when I call that greet module from the app.py it works fine. Why does it happen? Can anyone explain me or is there any good articles that can explain how does that works.


You need an init.py file in the test directory too

I have init.py file in the test dierectory too, that doesn't work also.
